# How find which Jdbc Url used in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a project which produces reports using .jrxml files. I want to findout what is the JDBC url used in that project. Where can I find that url in that project code? Please help me.

Comment: Do you use JasperReport Server to run the jrxml?

Comment: Yes. I am using Jaspersoft Server to run my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Data sources" directory in JasperReport Server and edit the database name which you are using for your reports.

There you can find the "URL (required): " properties.